# Odoo13 tree view show only one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

**I had a tree view xml which consists of the below code.**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="access_view_tree">
    <field name="name">Access tree</field>
    <field name="model">ka.access.rel</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Tree view" >
            <field name="id_ra_access"/>
            <field name="id_res_partner"/>
            <field name="partner_type"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Has a Model as below.**

```
_name = 'ka.access.rel'
_description = 'KA Partner REL'

id_ra_access = fields.Many2one('ra.access', "Access", required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True)
id_res_partner = fields.Many2one('res.partner', "Partner", required=True)
partner_type = fields.Selection([('1', 'Primary'), ('2', 'Secondary')], 'Partner Type', required=True, default=2)

_rec_name = 'id'

_defaults = {
    "partner_type": '2'
}
```

I could see only Form view is having all the three fields.
In tree view, I could see only one Column "ID"

[image: Tree View Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default tree view, your tree view definition was not loaded, If Odoo try to load it, it will raise a `ValidationError` because field `id_ra_Access` is not defined:

```
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error while validating view\n\nField `id_ra_Access` does not exist\n\nError context:\nView `Access tree`.
```

Check the manifest file and make sure to add the XML file (where you defined the tree view definition) to the `data` entry and use `id_ra_access` field name instead of `id_ra_Access`.

Comment: when i'm editing the question, "id_ra_access" went as a typo. Even in manifest the file is there. Hence the form view is working with all the files.. Only the tree view is the issue.

Comment: Please add the manifest and the view XML file.

Comment: Issue is resolved. Issue is the order of XML is not in proper order.